# Get total count and first 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 accounts.username
    ,COUNT(accounts.username) AS count
FROM relationships
JOIN accounts ON relationships.account = accounts.id
WHERE relationships.following = 4
    AND relationships.account IN (
        SELECT relationships.following
        FROM relationships
        WHERE relationships.account = 8
        );
```

I want to return the total count of accounts.username and the first 3 accounts.username (in no particular order). Unfortunately `accounts.username` and `COUNT(accounts.username)` cannot coexist. The query works fine removing one of the them. I don't want to send the request twice with different select bodies. The count column could span to 1000+ so I would prefer to calculate it in SQL rather in code.

The current query returns the error `Column 'accounts.username' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` which has not led me anywhere and this is different to other questions as I do not want to use the 'group by' clause. Is there a way to do this with `FOR JSON AUTO`?

The desired output could be:

```
+-------+----------+
| count | username |
+-------+----------+
| 1551  | simon1   |
| 1551  | simon2   |
| 1551  | simon3   |
+-------+----------+
```

or

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"count": 1551, "usernames": ["simon1", "simon2", "simon3"]}] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want here at all. Can you provide a [mcve] so everybody knows what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the total count of rows that satisfy the filter conditions (and where `username` is not null) in an additional column in your resultset, then you could use window functions:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    a.username,
    COUNT(a.username) OVER() AS cnt
FROM relationships r
JOIN accounts a ON r.account = a.id
WHERE 
    r.following = 4
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM relationships t1 WHERE r1.account = 8 AND r1.following = r.account
    )
;
```

Side notes:

- if `username` is not nullable, use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(a.username)`: this is more efficient since it does not require the database to check every value for nullity
- table aliases make the query easier to write, read and maintain
- I usually prefer `EXISTS` over `IN` (but here this is mostly a matter of taste, as both techniques should work fine for your use case)